# Is it possible to add condition where protocol is confirmed by either of class giving multiple options in where clause Self

Tags: ios, swift

lets suppose we have

```
protocol xyz {

}

class A: xyz {
}

class B: xyz {
}

class C: xyz{
}
```

extension of xyz is called only if the instance is of type either A or B class

```
extension xyz where Self: A, B {

}
```

Comment: your question is unclear please edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### So you want to define an extension to protocol XYZ when Self is A or B right?

The answer is: you can’t.

### However

You can achieve a similar result doing something like this

```
protocol XYZ { }
protocol AOrB: XYZ { }

class A: AOrB { }
class B: AOrB { }
class C: XYZ { }

extension XYZ where Self: AOrB {
    func foo() { }
}

A().foo()
B().foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify one class (either A or B) but not both, because Swift doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

A class can only extend one class. So extension xyz where Self: A, B both A and B are classes. You can't write an extension like that. Have a common conformation protocol for A and B. And write the extension for that type.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this extension to be implemented, either there is some shared interface that both A and B provide that you plan to use, or you plan to do some kind of type-checking inside of the functions.

If the former, then that's a protocol, and that's what you should be writing to, rather than two specific classes. Several answers here address that case. Create a protocol that covers the interface you need, and retroactively conform A and B to it by just saying they conform:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   // ... various methods that A already has ...
}
extension A: MyProtocol {}
```

Now, A conforms to MyProtocol.

If you're planning to do things like `type(of:)` to implement this extension, I strongly encourage you not to do that. Instead, create a protocol that provides the interface you want to use in your extension, and then conform A and B to it with extensions:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   // ... various methods that A doesn't have ...
}
extension A: MyProtocol {
   // ... implementations that bridge A to MyProtocol ...
}
```

In either case, you can then apply your extensions `where Self: MyProtocol`.

Alternately, if the conditional `type(of:)` code would be very different between A and B, then you can mix these approaches, and include class-specific code in extensions marked `where Self: A` and `where Self: B`.

The point is to think about the interfaces you need rather than focusing on "exactly one of these two classes."